# Designing a parametrized structure in c++

Tags: c++, class, input

I have a number of features of different basic types, that are parametrized say by numbers from 0 to 9, like

```
    int a[10];
    double b[10];
    char c[10];
```

So it makes sense to organize them in a structure:

```
Struct Features {
    int a;
    double b;
    char c;
};
Features f[10];
```

However, I'm required to read these features one by one. E.g. first a[0]...a[9], then b[0]...b[9] etc from an input like "a_features=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10", "b_features=0.5,...12.4" etc. For such input it's much easier to read the input into

```
int a[10]
```

than into

```
Features f[10]
```

What's the standard design in a situation like that?

UPDATE:

Thanks to all for prompt responses - my main goal is to have a clean design, performance-wise it's not critical. What strikes me as somewhat ugly, is that without the Features structure, I'll have almost the same code, repeated many times. Like

```
parse_features(a, "a_features, src_a); 
parse_features(b, "b_features", src_b);
```

If the containers are vectors and the size(10) comes from the user, I'd have to resize each vector separately and things like that.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @MutableSideEffect No.  Code review is for working code.  This is a design question which is on topic here.

Comment: @Lazycat I take it you want to avoid copying any data?

Comment: What's the difference from iterating over three arrays one time (with the separate `a`, `b` and `c` arrays), or iterating three times over one array (the array of structures `f`)? Both work equally well, and if the data belong together a structure is a better choice to group it.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I was unsure. Good to know, Thanks :)

Comment: If you *really* care about performance here (this is a critical piece of code which requires very high performance), you should consider the memory access pattern that each will give you. I don't know the specifics of your application so I can't give any guidance as to which will be more efficient for your situation.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Not really - just want to be clean in terms of design. See my update.

Comment: Design choices are fairly opinionated, especially since we don't have a lot of information about your problem domain. Honestly, storing data record-wise and column-wise are both common patterns. If you don't have detailed concerns about access patterns and performance, just pick the structure that looks the most maintainable to you.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Could be [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) though

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Depending on how the data is being used a structure of arrays can be more or less efficient than an array of structs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163722/is-my-understanding-of-aos-vs-soa-advantages-disadvantages-correct

Answer (score 0):

Is the integer `a[3]` related to the double `b[3]` and the char `c[3]` ? If yes, then it does make sense to group them into a structure.

If you have to read all the ints, then the doubles and then the chars, so be it.
"read an int into `f[3].a`" is just as easy as "read an int into `a[3]`".

If your input is structured like that, there's no way to avoid three loops. Three loops over the same array may look less elegant, but the rest of the program (the important part!) will be easier to understand if the data is grouped logically.