# SIMD programming: hybrid approch for data structure layout

Tags: cpu-architecture, sse, simd, avx, micro-optimization

The Intel Optimization Reference Manual
https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf
discusses the advantage of Structure-Of-Arrays (SoA) data layout for SIMD processing compared to the traditional Array-Of-Structures (AoS) layout. This is clear.

However, there's one argument I don't understand. On page 4-23 it says *"SoA can have the disadvantage of requiring more independent memory stream references. A computation that uses arrays X, Y, and Z (see Example 4-20) would require three separate data streams. This can require the use of more prefetches, additional address generation calculations, as well as having a greater impact on DRAM page access efficiency."* To mitigate this problem they recommend a hybrid approach (Example 4-22).

Can somebody please explain the "three separate data streams", the "prefetches" and "additional address generation calculations", and "impact on DRAM page access efficiency"?

At https://stackoverflow.com/a/40169187/3852630 Peter Cordes discusses two effects: Three different data streams for X, Y, and Z would tie up three registers for the addresses, and if the three arrays would be mapped to the same cache lines, frequent cache eviction would be a problem. However, registers are not a sparse resource on modern CPUs, and multi-way caches should mitigate the cache problem.

Comment: I think another part is at least partly relevant:
_Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 59. (H impact, L generality) 
If an inner loop writes to more than four arrays (four distinct cache lines), apply loop fission to break up the body of the loop such that only four arrays are being written to in each iteration of each of the resulting loops._