# Retrieve element from list of Object in cpp

Tags: c++

I want to retrieve each element from the list of object in cpp and we have classes like below:

```
class User{
public:
 
 bool isAvailable;
 string value;

};
class Users{

public:
 User dateFrom;
 User dateTo;
 User add1;
 User add2;

};
```

Now somewhere else I have created a list of objects of User like `std:: list<User> user-list`, stored data and then pushback to the list of the object now I want to get that particular data like dateFrom,dateTo, etc.

```
user-list.push_back(dateFrom);
user-list.push_back(dateTo);
```

Now I want to access the element of user-list like what we access in list l1 by index like.

Comment: where is "somewhere else" ? Please post a [mcve]. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Why are there four lists here? What is going on?

Comment: Aside: I would reject the name `std::list<User> dateFrom;` in code review, because how can a sequence of `User`s be a date? ditto the other members of `Users`

Comment: @Caleth,Hey just take it as an example I just need to ask how can I get the value of those?

Comment: The generic/conflicting names chosen and the apparenty parallel lists suggest this is an example of bad design. If so you should improve the design first. The obvious suggestion would be to have a `struct` which holds your four values (dateFrom, dateTo, add1 and add2) and then have a single list of that struct.

Comment: What value? Value from what? From these four lists? In what way? Would good if you could be more specific, show some example (pseudo) code of what you want to do.

Comment: @codepro123 If you want to find an item in a list, then the method is the obvious one, loop through the list testing each item in turn to see if it's the one you are looking for. At the moment the question is too vague to give better advice than that. If you don't know how to loop through a list, then please make it clear that that is the point of the question.

Comment: @john It is not always a bad design practice to have parallel lists , check [SoA vs Aos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163722/is-my-understanding-of-aos-vs-soa-advantages-disadvantages-correct)

Comment: It's totally unclear what you're trying to achieve. Where's the problem? We need so see more of your code. Never describe your code but rather show it.

Comment: the code you posted is just definitions of two classes. There isn't any instance of anything that you could access elements of in the code you posted. Are you asking how to access an element in a `std::list` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818, yes in the above case just elaborate.

Comment: elaborate? You should post a [mcve] or at least an attempt so we can know what problem you are facing. Currently the quesiton is rather unclear. There are different ways to access elements in a list. You can iterate the list with a range based for loop. What you actually want, we cannot know

Comment: do you know how to acces an element in a `std::list<int>` ? It is the same when that list is member of a class and it is also the same for a `std::list<User>`

Comment: @ idclev 463035818, hey, thank you for your comments now I have edited above.

Comment: If you want to access the elements of the list by index, you shouldn't use `std::list` in the first place but rather `std::vector`. You mention a _"list l1"_ at the end of your question, this is unclear which _l1_ are you talking about? Your question is still very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess of what you might want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class User {
public:    
  bool isAvailable;
  string value;
};

int main()
{
  User someuser;
  someuser.value = "Some user";
  someuser.isAvailable = true;
  User someotheruser;
  someotheruser.value = "Some other user";
  someotheruser.isAvailable = true;

  std::vector<User> user_list;    // <<<< using std::vector here
  user_list.push_back(someotheruser);
  user_list.push_back(someuser);

  cout << user_list[0].value << "\n";
  cout << user_list[1].value << "\n";
}
```

We use a `std::vector` here instead of a `std::list` because you mention you wanted to access the elements of the list via an index.

Output is:

```
Some other user
Some user
```

Disclaimer: This code is still very poor, for example there are no constructors whatsoever.